# Cast struct object to dynamic trait object

Tags: struct, rust, casting, traits

This is a simpler version of my code:

```rust
type Res = Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;
// defined before-hand
pub trait Attr {
    fn method(&self) -> Res;
}

// a struct, a block of code provided by user
// which is unknown by far
pub struct S;

// the trait implemented for provided struct
// user does this manually
// which is unknown by far
impl Attr for S {
    fn method(&self) -> Res {
        Ok(())
    }
}

// in order to use the struct and its implemented method
// a possible way may be cast struct type to dynamic trait object

type Item = dyn Fn(&dyn Attr) -> Res;

pub fn use_method(f: &Item) {}

fn main() {
    // casting happens here
    // and do this job in macro, here is simplified version
    let m = &(<S as Attr>::method) as &Item;
    use_method(m);
}
```

It is required to tackle a struct, a block of code and its implementation both of which are unknown and provided by user. A rough direction may be using a trait as dynamic trait bounds which converted from struct object, but the compiler complain:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:30:13
   |
4  |     fn method(&self) -> Res;
   |     ------------------------ found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r S) -> _`
...
30 |     let m = &(<S as Attr>::method) as &Item;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r (dyn Attr + 'r)) -> _`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r (dyn Attr + 'r)) -> std::result::Result<(), Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>>`
```

How can I get it done? Is there any other way?

Comment: I didn't understand your question very well but `method()` accepts an shared ref to a type that implements `Attr` trait. `Item` contains a `Fn` which would accept a Attr trait object. They are not same. So I guess casting shouldn't be possible. If you change definition of `method()` to have the same signature as `Item`, it should work. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b086eba8673b14710a3a2788caace519)

Comment: changing the signature of 'method()' cause the trait 'Attr' cannot be made into an object.

Comment: That's why I placed `where Self: Sized` on `method()` to make that particular method object-unsafe. The trait object can still be constructed. I added a playground link above which does this and compiles too. Here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b086eba8673b14710a3a2788caace519

Comment: Can you use a closure instead? E.g. `let m = |s: &dyn Attr| s.method(); use_method(&m);`?